# Naming convention for Lattice isomorphism theorem

Tags: group-theory

I am confused how the words “lattice isomorphism” in lattice isomorphism theorem relates to the results other than the first one. To be more concrete, I will discuss in terms of the statement of the theorem as given in the wiki.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem

I am confused why the 2nd to 5th bullets are necessary to prove that the lattice structure is preserved as we move to $G/N$.

Specifically, why are these results necessary to prove the preservation of the lattice structure.

1. if $A \leq B$, then $|B:A| = B/N:A/N\\$
2. $\left<A,B\right>/N = \left<A/N, B/N\right>$
3. $(A \cap B)/N = A/N \cap B/N$
4. $A \unlhd B$ iff $A/N \unlhd B/N$

Because:

We can guarantee that if there is a lattice “line” between two subgroups $A/N$ and $B/N$, then there is also a lattice “line” between $A$ and $B$ because otherwise there would be an intermediary subgroup which implies another intermediate subgroup between the subgroups $A/N$ and $B/N$ which doesn’t exist because the lattice line, by definition, implies that there is no intermediary subgroup.

VIA a similar mindset, we can also prove that the number of lattice lines that touches any one subgroup is also preserved as we move to $G/N$. We can also prove that the minimal number of lattice lines needed to go from $N$ to the $A$ is the same as the minimal number of lattice lines needed to go from $1N$ to $A/N$. I think we can already show the preservation of the lattice structure just from these observations.

All of this is given just by the first bullet in the lattice isomorphism theorem which is

> $A \leq B$ iff $A/N \leq B/N$

So, we actually don’t need these other results to prove the “lattice isomorphism”. Even in terms of sublattices, we don’t really need these results. So, why are these results also part of the **LATTICE ISOMORPHISM** theorem?

I feel like these results actually are necessary and I am making some mistake in my argument because why would they name it the “lattice” isomorphism theorem if only the first result relates to the preservation of the lattice structure anyways.

Comment: To be specific, the name lattice isomorphism theorem was given in Dummit and Foote.

Comment: The subgroup lattice is often "decorated" with additional information, such as the index being a multiplicative label on inclusions, and a special sublattice given by the "is a normal subgroup  of" relation. The Lattice Isomorphism Theorem tells you that this correspondence preserves not just the bare order, lub, glb, information, but is also index-preserving and normality-preserving. Why would you *not* want to know that?

Comment: Also, note that lattices have two "lives": they are both partially ordered sets in which every pair of elements have a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound; **and** they are algebras with two binary operations, $\wedge$ and $\vee$, satisfying certain identities (e.g., see the two definitions in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order))). From the algebraic point of view, you want to show the correspondence respects both $\vee$ (bullet point 3) and $\wedge$ (bullet point 4). So bullet point 1 gives the order version, 3 and 4 give the algebraic version.

Comment: I thank you gave the answer, thanks. I did not know about this algebra property. I’ll look into this!

Comment: By the way, you can have an order-preserving map between lattices that is not a lattice homomorphism (that is, it does not preserve glbs and lubs). E.g., take the lattice consisitingb of $0,x,y,1$ with $0$ the least element, $1$ the greatest element, and $x$ and $ y$ incomparable. And the lattice consisitingbof $0,a,b,c,1$, with $0$ smallest element, $1$ largest, $a$ and $b$ incomparable, and $c$ their least upper bound. The map sendin $0\mapsto 0, x\mapsto a, y\mapsto b, 1\mapsto 1$ is an order preserving morphism that does not preserve lubs, so it is not a lattice morphism.